# What is the "moderator for the relationship" in interactive regression model?

Tags: econometrics

I have an interactive regresison model as below:

$Y_{i,t} = \beta_0 + \beta_1$$D_i$ + $\beta_2$$P_{i,t}$ + $\beta_3$($D_i$$P_{i,t}$) + other covariates + error terms

In this model, why $D_i$ is called as **the moderator for the relationship between $P_{i,t}$ and $Y_{i,t}$**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [moderator variables](https://www.statisticshowto.com/moderating-variable/) are  by definition variables that affect the strength of the relationship between one variable and another variable, and that is exactly what interaction effect does (it allows $P$ to have different effect depending on whether $D=1$ or $D=0$).

This is actually not terminology used widely in economics, but it is used widely in [psychology](https://www.psychologyinaction.org/psychology-in-action-1/2015/02/06/mediating-and-moderating-variables-explained) and some other fields (although I seen it used in few behavioral economics papers). In economics, outside few specific subfields people usually call it interaction term.